# "Cannot form reference to void" error even with `requires(!std::is_void_v<T>)`

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm writing a pointer class and overloading the dereference operator `operator*`, which returns a reference to the pointed-to object. When the pointed-to type is not void this is fine, but we cannot create a reference to void, so I'm trying to disable the `operator*` using a requires clause when the pointed-to type is void.

However, I'm still getting compiler errors from GCC, Clang, and MSVC for the void case even though it does not satisfy the requires clause.

Here is a minimal example and compiler explorer link (https://godbolt.org/z/xbo5v3d1E).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct MyPtr {
    T* p;

    T& operator*() requires(!std::is_void_v<T>)
    {
        return *p;
    }
};

int main() {
    int x = 42;

    MyPtr<int> i_ptr{&x};
    *i_ptr = 41;

    MyPtr<void> v_ptr{&x};
    std::cout << *static_cast<int*>(v_ptr.p) << '\n';

    std::cout << x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the error (in Clang):

```
<source>:7:6: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
    T& operator*()
     ^
<source>:20:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'MyPtr<void>' requested here
    MyPtr<void> v_ptr{&x};
                ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:7:6: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
    T& operator*()
     ^
<source>:20:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'MyPtr<void>' requested here
    MyPtr<void> v_ptr{&x};
                ^
1 error generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

However, if I change the return type of `operator*` from `T&` to `auto&`, then it works in all 3 compilers. If I use trailing return type `auto ... -> T&` I also get errors in all 3 compilers.

Is this a triple compiler bug, user error, or is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the Nelfeal's answer, let me give an alternative solution. The problem is not in the dependence of `requires` condition on `T`, but is in the return type `T&`. Let's use a [helper type trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference):

```
std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T> operator*() 
requires(!std::is_void_v<T>)
{ 
    ...
}
```

It works [because](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference#Notes) `std::add_lvalue_reference_t<void> = void`, which makes `operator*()` signature valid for `T = void`.

Comment: I was looking for something that gives the error message as if you put `auto&` as the return type. After removing the `requires`, this apparently does, although through a different mechanism. Good find.

Answer (score 3):

The `requires` clause doesn't matter because `T` is a parameter of the class template. Once `T` is known, the class can be instantiated, but if `T` is `void`, that instantiation fails because of the member function signature.

You can either put that `requires` on the entire class, or make the member function a template like this:

```
template<typename U = T>
U& operator*() requires(!std::is_void_v<U> && std::is_same_v<T, U>)
{
    return *p;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YWv4vxqhb)

Making the return type `auto&` is almost the same thing: the return type is deduced by replacing `auto` with an imaginary type template parameter `U` and then performing template argument deduction. Note that the version above with `requires` makes the compilation error clear if you try to use this function with `U=void`: GCC says `template argument deduction/substitution failed: constraints not satisfied`.

I don't think there is a way to reproduce exactly what an `auto&` return type does by making the function a template. Something like this might come close:

```
template<typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>, U>& operator*() 
{
    return *p;
}
```

Compare what you're trying with the equivalent using `std::enable_if` (without concepts):

```
template<std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>, bool> = true>
T& operator*()
{
    return *p;
}
```

This will give you an error like `no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>'`, because SFINAE wouldn't work in this situation where `T` is not a parameter of the function template.

Technically, you can also change the return type depending on whether `T` is `void`, but this is probably a bad idea:

```
using R = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, int, T>;
R& operator*()
{
    // calling this with T=void will fail to compile
    // 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
    return *p;
}
```

Comment: But then why does it compile when `auto&` is used in place of `T&` for the return type?

Comment: @mCoding A member function of a class template is not instantiated unless used, but a function signature has to be valid for all `T` used to instantiate a class template. `auto&` gives you a valid signature.

Comment: @mCoding Edited, hopefully that clears things up.